# Jquery content slider, how to duplicate without redundant code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I add an additional slider on this page without adding duplicate functions and additional css classes?

I know how to duplicate them no problem but I'd like someone to teach me the proper way to reuse the current code.

I'm going to take a guess and say that I'm probably going to need the "this" keyword.

```
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/chaddly/mR3Vn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

some more flip's-

```
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/mR3Vn/8/)

Comment: Ok cool.  So the difference is we are using classes instead of IDs and also using "this" to invoke identity.  Awesome!  Is there any easy, simple way to make all other objects automatically close when they lose focus or another item is expanded?

Comment: This can be improved further,, but it's just to show you the way -

Comment: Ooooh! Works beautifully! Thanks guys!

Comment: Can't close them.  They re-open.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 2**

Modify the code with:

```
$('.panel').hide();    
$(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
```

Hide all the panels first and then open the one currently clicked.

Comment: this will break the toggle effect.. see here  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/mR3Vn/4/

Comment: works great, besides the abrupt transitioning.  http://jsfiddle.net/chaddly/mR3Vn/6/

Comment: I just saw that! :( Whose going to fix it?

Comment: So how do we hide() softly :P?

Comment: I need to fix the case of when you click on an open panel, in which case, you need to close it, not hide it and then reopen it, which is what my code is doing.